# Button doesn't work when adding to fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I have a button in an fragment that when I clicked on it nothing happens at all

this is the java code of the fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    EditText etAddPost;
    Button addPostImage;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("posts");;

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        etAddPost =rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAddPost);
        addPostImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.addPostBtn);
        addPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String postText = etAddPost.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(postText)){
                    etAddPost.setError("لا يمكنك ترك هذا الحقل فارغا");
                }
                else {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("postContent", postText);
                    myRef.push().setValue(map);
                    etAddPost.setText("");
                }
            }
        });        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
"http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

and this is my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color3"
    tools:context="com.mk.playAndLearn.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/etAddPost"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:hint="ماذا يخطر في بالك؟"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried a lot to solve this problem but I couldn't but I am feeling that solving the problem is easy so I hope that any one helps me to solve this problem I tried to change the button type and use ImageButton instead but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Does the button animate when you press it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've problems with xml layout. Your recyclerview laying over linear layout. Change the layout as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color3"
    tools:context="com.mk.playAndLearn.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addPostBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/send"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/etAddPost"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:hint="ماذا يخطر في بالك؟"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have removed the frame layout and used linear Layout instead but that doesn't solve the problem